# Update Grid Row Cell Image when a user selects image from dialog

Tags: c#, wpf

I have an Image and a button side by side in a DevExpress grid, when the user clicks the button I would like the user to be able to select from a FileDialog a new image that should immediately show in the Image Field. When the user updates the rest of the fields in the row the IPropertyChange event should fire and store the row. How can I achieve this in WPF?

XAML:

```
<dxg:GridColumn FieldName="Image" Header="Image" >
     <dxg:GridColumn.CellTemplate>
          <DataTemplate>
               <DockPanel>
                    <Image Source="{Binding RowData.Row.Image, Converter={StaticResource BinaryImageConverter}}" Width="100" />
                    <Button x:Name="BrowseFilePath" Height="20" Width="20" Content="..." Visibility="Hidden" CommandParameter="{Binding RowData.Row}" />
                    <!--<Button x:Name="BrowseFilePath" Height="20" Width="20" Content="..." Visibility="Hidden" Command="{Binding Source={x:Static local:FacilitiesBrowseImagePathDialog.BrowsePathCommand}}" CommandParameter="{Binding RowData.Row}"  />-->
               </DockPanel>
               <DataTemplate.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsMouseOver, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=dxg:GridRow}}" Value="True">
                         <Setter TargetName="BrowseFilePath" Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" />
                    </DataTrigger>
                </DataTemplate.Triggers>
            </DataTemplate>
       </dxg:GridColumn.CellTemplate>
 </dxg:GridColumn>
```

Comment: Note: I've written the code to get the file from System.Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog(), and read the file in a byte[] for storing to the db.

Comment: Note that it's better to use `Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog` in WPF.

Comment: Could you please explain it more detailed? What do you mean by _When the user updates the rest of the fields in the row the IPropertyChange event should fire_? The `PropertyChanged` event is defined by the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface, which should be implemented by your view model to update the view. Do you want your view to fire that events?